# How to get floated divs (with unknown width) to stay on one line

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, css-float, less

Here's the markup:

```
<nav id="the-nav">
    <span id="backward"><i class="icon-backward"></i></span>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <span class="active-module"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="..."></a>
             </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="..."></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="modules">
            <div class="module active">
                <a href="..."><i class="icon-*"></i></a> <!-- a few bootstrap icons are used -->
                <a href="..."><i class="icon-*"></i></a>
                <a href="..."><i class="icon-*"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="module">
                <a href="..."><i class="icon-*"></i></a>
                <a href="..."><i class="icon-*"></i></a>
                <a href="..."><i class="icon-*"></i></a>
                <!-- More items here... -->
            </div>

            <!-- More modules here... --> 

        </div>
    </div>

    <span id="forward"><i class="icon-forward"></i></span>
</nav>
```

And here's the less/css:

```
#the-nav {
  @itemDimension: 35px;
  @dropdownWidth: 150px;

  background: white;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;

  /* Square mixin for items and navigator arrows. */
  .square () {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: @itemDimension;
    padding: 3px;
    width: @itemDimension;
  }

  div, span { float: left; }

  /* Module Dropdown */
  .dropdown {
    font-size: 12px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: @dropdownWidth;

    /* Make dropdown drop "up". */
    &.open > .dropdown-menu {
      bottom: 100%;
      top: inherit;
    }

    .active-module {
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      width: @dropdownWidth;
    }

    img {
      height: 30px;
      width: 30px;
    }
  }

  .wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;

    /* Set width so that there is just enough room for the forward and back
     * arrows. As a fallback, give it a percentage width. */
    width: 88%;
    width: -webkit-calc(100% ~'-' 2*@itemDimension+@dropdownWidth);
    width: -moz-calc(100% ~'-' 2*@itemDimension+@dropdownWidth);
    width: calc(100% ~'-' 2*@itemDimension+@dropdownWidth);
  }

  /* Forward/backward scoll buttons */
  #forward, #backward {
    .square;
    padding: 7px 0 0 10px;

    &:hover {
      background: lightblue;
    }
  }

  /* Module items */
  .module > a {  
    .square;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;

    i {
      display: block !important;
      font-size: 120%;
      margin-top: 6px !important;
    }
  }

  .module:not(.active) { display: none; }
}
```

The module shown (determined by the dropdown) is set using javascript.

I want this entire navbar to stay on one line. Currently, it works in Chrome, but not in Firefox. In Firefox, the contents of each module wrap to a new line so that the entire navbar spans multiple lines. I want this to all stay on one line.

I have a feeling there is some combination of `display`, `float`, and `white-space` that will get what I want, but I am not sure what that combination that is.

**UPDATE** [Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bolnd) is a codepen that shows exactly what I want. Again, this works on chrome, but not on firefox. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bolnd

Comment: The question is too extensive. A jsfiddle would help a lot.

Comment: A jsfiddle is practically needed due to the fact you use less/css

Comment: @falsarella Ok, thanks for the tip. Added a codepen.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `float: left` and add `display: inline-block;` to `div, span`:

```
div, span { display: inline-block; }
```

Recalculate the `.wrapper` width considering the paddings:

```
width: calc(100% ~'-' 2*@itemDimension+@dropdownWidth+2*@itemPadding+2*@directionalLeftPadding);
```

[See the Codepen with the changes](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cIfEF)

---

Full CSS LESS code:

```
/* Bootstrap */
@import url('http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css');
/* FontAwesome */
@import url('http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css');

@directionalLeftPadding: 10px;
@itemPadding: 3px;
@itemDimension: 35px;
@dropdownWidth: 150px;

.square () {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: @itemDimension;
  padding: @itemPadding;
  width: @itemDimension;
}

div, span { display: inline-block; }

nav {
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Module Dropdown */
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: @dropdownWidth;

  /* Make dropdown drop "up". */
  &.open > .dropdown-menu {
    top: inherit;
    bottom: 100%;
  }

  .active-module {
    width: @dropdownWidth;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }

  img {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
  }
}

.wrapper {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;

  /* Set width so that there is just enough room
   * for the forward and back arrows. As a
   * fallback, give it a percentage width. */
  width: 88%;
  width: -webkit-calc(100% ~'-' 2*@itemDimension+@dropdownWidth+2*@itemPadding+2*@directionalLeftPadding);
  width: -moz-calc(100% ~'-' 2*@itemDimension+@dropdownWidth+2*@itemPadding+2*@directionalLeftPadding);
  width: calc(100% ~'-' 2*@itemDimension+@dropdownWidth+2*@itemPadding+2*@directionalLeftPadding);
}

/* Forward/backward scoll buttons */
#forward, #backward {
  float: left;
  .square;
  padding: 7px 0 0 @directionalLeftPadding;

  &:hover {
    background: lightblue;
  }
}

/* Module items */
.module > span {  
  .square;
  text-align: center;

  &:not(:last-child) { border-right: 1px solid black; }

  i {
    display: block !important;
    font-size: 120%;
    margin-top: 6px !important;
  }
}

.module:not(.active) { display: none; }
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is there a reason `@itemPadding` and `@directionalLeftPadding` are used in the wrapper's width calculation? Also, why is `@directionalLeftPadding` used for `#forward` and `#backward` padding? More specifically, what is `@directionalLeftPadding`?

Comment: There were a padding with 10px at both #forward and #backward. I just extracted that to a variable to include at the wrapper's width calculation. It needs to calculate the padding because the width does not consider the padding - which means that if you do not subtract the width from 100%, it will not fit well. Imagine that the 100% represents 1000px, if you have the forward sign and backward sign with 30px each and an aditional dropdown with 150px, it will subtract 210px in total, which means that the wrapper will have 790px. (continue)

Comment: Til here everything ok, but, now, you put a padding of 3px to .square and 10px to forward and backward: it will need more horizontal space, but it will not increase its width, and if it does not increase the width, the wrapper's width won't change and then won't fit at 100%. So, subtracting the paddings from wrapper's width  makes the second part of the trick. ;)